# Calling an Activity from aar library gives a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/ViewModelKt

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to android development.

I have developed a library and compiled it in an aar file. Now in another project I include the library, add the activity to the manifest and try to start the activity. I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/ViewModelKt
```

Both the project and library are at compileSdk = 34 and are using kotlin compose.

Anybody have an idea why this is happening? Thank you

EDIT
Here is the build.gradle.kts from the library:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.8.10"
}

android {
    namespace = "*removed the namespace*"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }


    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }

}

dependencies {


    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview-android:1.5.2")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")

    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

EDIT 2
The build.gradle of the project in which I am including the library

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.test"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.test"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation(files("/home/path-to-aar/library.aar"))
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

Comment: Is that `ViewModel` logic a part of your library? And please show how you included it in the `build.gradle`

Comment: I think ViewModelKt is from the androidx library, it's not from mine

Comment: I mean am I correct that you've included the logic related to `ViewModel` into your aar, and included `androidx` dependency there too, so that it be included transitively to your project? I want to localize the problem. Could you please also show how you included it in the `build.gradle`?

Comment: You mean the in the actual library. I'll post the library's build.gradle as an edit in the original post.
@VladGuriev

Comment: I mean the `implementation` line in the `app` module's `build.gradle` where you include your library

Comment: @VladGuriev I'll add the build.grade of the project in which I am including the library as an aar

Comment: @VladGuriev I am still stuck, if you have any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: I would go with publishing the aar to local maven repository and then including it with `{ isTransitive = true }` (as far as I remember, it doesn't work with `implementation(files(...))`)